# Targeting the parent of the current :target element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target the parent element of whatever element is the current `:target` of the page.

Here is, roughly, my table structure (the parts that matter)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><a class="anchor" id="teammate_row_1"></a>Name 1</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><a class="anchor" id="teammate_row_2"></a>Name 2</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><a class="anchor" id="teammate_row_3"></a>Name 3</strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I put the anchor element as part of the table this way instead of the entire row, because I have a header on my website which means that if I anchored the entire row, the row would be hidden behind my header after it scrolls to the element, so the anchor element *must* remain in this spot.

This is my CSS for the anchor element

```
a.anchor {
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    top: -90px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Now, when someone clicks a link and gets to one of these anchor points, I want to sort of highlight the row that is selected to be a different color, so that it stands out more.

I am aware of the `:target` CSS selector, which should allow me to change the CSS of a the element selected, however, I do not need to change the *actual* target's CSS, I need to change it's parents css.

I've tried the following CSS selectors:

- :target > tr
- :target > strong > tr
- :target < tr
- :target < strong < tr
- :target:parent
- :target:parent:parent (Wasn't sure if  was counted as a parent)

But nothing has given me any results.

I've seen in the comments that it's mentioned there is no CSS parent selector, but I could also use JavaScript/jQuery as a solution. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't access the parent (or any other ancestor) with CSS

Comment: @ItayGal I wouldn't mind a jQuery/JavaScript solution

Comment: you need to simply change the background?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, of the parent of the `:target`

Comment: Then simply use JQuery `yourElement.parent()` or `yourElement.parentElement`

Comment: @ItayGal Can I use `:target` as a selector in jQuery? edit: I see now that I can https://api.jquery.com/target-selector/

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771091/8620333 (use pseudo element as a trick)